# Only top-level tags without sub-tags offered in webform contact filter

Tags: webform-civicrm

We have tags to distinguish the set of grades taught in organizations of type School (1st snippet below). These tags are used in a form to filter the list of contacts (schools) available to select. This filter is working and has been working for over a year. The webform component, however, no longer shows the tag in the filter. Something changed since the creation of the form and, though the form continues to filter correctly, the filter configuration itself is not showing the correct tag. In fact it only offers a subset (top level w/o sub-entries) of the tags defined in Civi (2nd snippet). Glad it still works, but apprehensive that I don't understand how!

CiviCRM 5.40.4, Drupal 7.82, webform 7.x-4.24, webform_civicrm 7.x-5.6

[image: Tags in Civi]

---

[image: Tags in webform filter]

Comment: I noticed that one too, in 5.35.2.  Same situation, where tags are nested.  Bug in webform I guess?

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a bug in Webform civiCRM version 7x-5.6.  I've raised [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm/issues/3232416)

Comment: Thanks @Andy Clark.